# Custom feed to only show articles from followed users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have been referencing [this](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) rails tutorial to try to create a feed where only articles belonging to users who have accepted my friend requests appear in my feed.

However, i have a different schema and user model from the tutorial (i have an extra step where friend request is pending to be accepted). The below method in my user model does not filter out friendships which have not been accepted, hence articles of unconfirmed friends are appearing my feed, which is not what I want.

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :received_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id"
  has_many :active_friends, -> { where(friendships: { accepted: true}) }, through: :friendships, source: :friend
  has_many :received_friends, -> { where(friendships: { accepted: true}) }, through: :received_friendships, source: :user
  has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendships: { accepted: false}) }, through: :friendships, source: :friend
  has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { accepted: false}) }, through: :received_friendships, source: :user

  def feed
    friend_ids = "SELECT friend_id FROM friendships
                     WHERE  user_id = :user_id"
    Article.where("user_id IN (#{friend_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.boolean "accepted", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**Pages controller**

```
def home
    @feed = current_user.feed.all
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= render @feed %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your case I think the key is here WHERE (user_id = :user_id AND accepted = true), I get accepted field from friendships schema.

```
  def feed
    friend_ids = "SELECT friend_id FROM friendships
                     WHERE (user_id = :user_id AND accepted = 't')"
    Article.where("user_id IN (#{friend_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
  end
```